# Ending manual selection of contours in Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, contour

I am trying to manually place contour labels using `matplotlib.pyplot.clabel` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make example contours
N=20
X = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N)
Y = np.linspace(0.0, 25.0, N)
Z = np.ones((N,N))
i=0
j=0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        Z[i][j] = i+j
        j += 1
    i += 1
Z = Z.transpose()

# Make subplots figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(8,5))
im =  axes[0].contour(X, Y, Z, colors = 'k')
CLS = plt.clabel(im, colors = 'k', fmt = '%2.1f', fontsize=12, manual=True)
im2 =  axes[1].contourf(X, Y, Z)
fig.show()
```

This code produces the following figure, which adds contour labels to the different contours as you left-click on them:

[image]

The message on the console as python tracks the clicks is:

> Select label locations manually using first mouse button.
>   End manual selection with second mouse button.

The problem is that the right-click does not end the event recording, and  I am unable to go past this point in the script at run time. I have tried this both on Windows and Mac using Spyder, and the *second mouse button* is not recorded.

**EDIT 1: As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out, the *second mouse button* is actually the scroll wheel, not the right button. I have decided to leave the question as is because I think this is not clear for every user of matplotlib.**

I would like to know how to end the manual selection process so that the program continues and I am able to retrieve a figure like this:

[image]

but with contour labels, of course. I have tried this process with figure plotter in Automatic, Tkinter and Qt5, with no success.

Comment: The right mousebutton is the "third", use the second instead, which should be the mousewheel. I have no idea though what happens for mice with only two buttons.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest . I was able to get it working through this insight. I have gotten it to work both in Windows with TouchPad and Mac with the Magic Mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said, the *second mouse button* is actually the scroll wheel, not the right button. If you have a mouse with all three buttons then this is the solution.

For Mac users with a Magic Mouse, the solution is not as straightforward. I was able to make it work with the 3rd party application [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai). Once downloaded, go to **System Preferences >> Security & Privacy**. Under the section *Allow the apps below to control your computer.*, enable BetterTouchTool.

Then, open the app and under **Select Trigger** choose **1 Finger Middle Click**. Then on the right, under the section **Actions Assigned to Selected Trigger**, choose **Middle Click**. Once this is done, pushing the middle of the Magic Button will do the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer you are expecting, but I have faced a similar problem myself with `clabel` and have found my way around it using the `manual` keyword in a different way. All you have to do is to provide a tuple of tuples, each containing the coordinates of the desired label (the coordinates as if you were reading on the graph with x and y tick labels). The algorithm will then add your label to the closest contour. There is a bit of trial and error, but at least I found it to be more reliable than the mouse selection.

```
ax.clabel(contourObject, colors='', fmt='', fontsize=,
          manual=((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)), inline=True,
          inline_spacing=)
```

Comment: Thanks @Patol75. I knew about this feature but I wanted to set them manually to avoid having to guess the axis coordinates of the locations I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on PyCharm/windows 10.

A clic on the roll button ends the recording and when I add `inline=False` in clabel function, I can remove the last label added.

You may find a solution in the matplotlib *Event handling and picking*
documentation : [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html)